# Using redirection plugin to pass URLs as lowercase to wordpress

Tags: redirect

have been experiencing a problem yesterday. My site is in Hebrew language. MY site is built on Wordpress. The problem is related to escaped encoded posts URL only. IF the post URL has escaped encode in uppercase it works, if in lowercase, it returns 404. I want both to pass without a problem.

For example: http://domain.com/%d7%9e%d7%a6%d7%9c%d7%9e%d7%95%d7%aa/ (this is what my site have)

Google crawled it as: http://domain.com/%D7%9E%D7%a6%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA/ (this returned 404)

Is there any option to use the REDIRECTION plugin for wordpress to PASS (not redirect) the URLs o wordpress will see them as lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way is to implement a 404 handler of some kind.  It should see if there are lowercase letters in the url and then redirect to the uppercase version.

If you need help implementing a 404 handler, try looking at a simple plugin that handles 404s, such as this one: http://crowdfavorite.com/wordpress/plugins/404-notifier/

I'm not sure why you would want to pass instead of redirecting.  If you redirect with a 301 status code, Google should update their index.